# How to make a local JBOSS AS 7 serve static resources?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6, staticresource

As a standard, my static resources need to stay in a centralized location, out of my EARs / WARs (so that they can be updated without rolling out a new release for minor JS/CSS changes).

My HTML imports are relative, eg:

```xml
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/myApp/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This means that the URLs to resources are different on every server (development, test, production..):

On `dev-foobar.com`:

> **dev-foobar.com**/resources/myApp/js/bootstrap.min.js

On `tst-foobar.com`:

> **tst-foobar.com**/resources/myApp/js/bootstrap.min.js

On `foobar.com`:

> **foobar.com**/resources/myApp/js/bootstrap.min.js

---

**But when I'm on my LOCAL Jboss (`localhost:8080`), how can I instruct it to serve the same static resources to achieve the following URL ?**

> **localhost:8080**/resources/myApp/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBoss handles all the static resources through a folder called `welcome-content` under `$JBOSS_HOME`:

> C:\Program Files\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\**welcome-content**

Simply put something there, and it will be exposed in the root context.

For example, it's sufficient to copy the sample folders and file described in the question:

> C:\Program Files\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\**welcome-content\resources**\myApp\js\bootstrap.min.js

to end with the file (but not the folders) being accessible through the URL:

> **localhost:8080/resources/myApp/js/bootstrap.min.js**

Well done, Red Hat !

Comment: Is it possible to locate to a different folder other than the welcom folder.. How can we give a different folder location for the same.